# Combination of N strings with K letters

Tags: java, android, search, contacts

I have tried multiple ways but i did not get the exact solution.

I have a requirement like phone contact search,
In the keypad contains

```
1-nothing
2-ABC
3-DEF
4-GHI
..
.
```

Now I am pressing 23 buttons then search goes like below

```
AD , AE , AF , BD , BE , BF , CD , CE , CF
```

In the same scenario, I am pressing 234 then

```
ADG , ADH , ADI , AEG , AEH , AEI , AFG , AFH , AFI , BDG , BDH , BDI ..........
```

Comment: This is not a place where you can post your "requirements". Post your code, if you want some help with it.

Comment: You really need to show your work so far. Anyways try the other approach. Convert each contact name to its corresponding sequence of digits. The algorithm should become much clearer to you, then.

Comment: I have tried multiple scenario's but i get the entire letter letter combinations, not for like above

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Regular Expressions here. If you press 234 then you can construct the regex `^[ABC][DEF][GHI]` (with the `^` optional if you only want to match from the beginning of the string). You may want to make sure to use case-insensitive matching, too.

You can also do this in Android, see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String).

(Edit: @JasonC's answer of converting names to numbers first is also a good option).

Answer (score 1):

If you convert each contact name to its corresponding sequence of digits, the search will be far more straightforward, and you don't have to worry about creating combinations of letters.

```
Bob => 262
John => 5646
Steve => 78373
Show => 7469
Your => 9687
Work => 9675
Please => 753273
```

Good luck.